# How to create ID number without duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table called `Student` with these columns:

```
First name 
Last name
Class ID
Class
```

I want to create an ID for student, I tried using `Row_number Over Partiton` but I seem to not be getting what looking for but more of it resetting itself,  this is outcome I am trying to get.

```
First Last   Class    ClasID  ID (outcome looking for)
------------------------------------
John  Brown  Math     M21     ID01
John  Brown  English  E31     ID01
Tom   Bank   Math     M21     ID02
John  Brown  Gym      G41     ID01
Tim   Brown  English  E31     ID03
```

Comment: That table should not be called `Student` in the first place. There should be three tables: `Student` (one row per student, with individual data for each student, including a `student_id`), `Class` (one row per class, with characteristics of each class, including a `class_id`), and a table like the one you illustrated, called perhaps `Student_Class`, listing only the pairs of `(student_id, class_id)` to show which classes each student is enrolled in. So, question: Is this something you came up with? Is it an assignment in your class?

Comment: If it's an assignment, I would tell the instructor this is not a good data model, and we shouldn't be encouraged to learn on bad data models. If it's something you came up with, you might want to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over(order by last, first) as id
from student
```

This assigns the same `id` to rows where the first and last names are the same.

If you *really* want a format like `IDnn` (which does not makes a lot of sense in my view), then you can format and concatenate:

```
select t.*, 
    'ID' || to_char(dense_rank() over(order by last, first), '09') as id
from student
```

This will fail to generate the proper string if there are more than 99 distinct students.

Answer (score 0):

The dense_rank solution offered by @GMB produces an "id" as part of a given result set, not as an inherent identifier of a given student.  The classic method of permanently assigning an ID to an entity (student, employee, class, etc) is to create a SEQUENCE, then an on_insert TRIGGER to populate the ID column with the next_value of the sequence.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE STUDENTS
  2  (
  3    STUDENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
  4  , FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
  5  , LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
  6  , CONSTRAINT STUDENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY
  7    (
  8      STUDENT_ID
  9    )
 10    ENABLE
 11  );

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
SQL> --
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
  2   START WITH     1
  3   INCREMENT BY   1
  4  ;

Sequence created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STUDENTS_TRIG
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON students
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    :new.student_ID := ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  6  END;
  7  /

Trigger created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> insert into students (first_name,
  2                        last_name)
  3              values ('Ed',
  4                      'Stevens'
  5                     )
  6  ;

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.18
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL> select * from students;

STUDENT_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Ed                   Stevens

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
SQL> --
SQL> drop trigger students_trig;

Trigger dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL> drop table students purge;

Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
SQL> drop sequence id_seq;

Sequence dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Starting with version 12, you don't have to create the sequence or trigger, just declare the ID column to be an 'identity' column.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to research that concept.